# Change class of html element when specific option/value is selected in select field

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onchange

I want to check if a specific option/value is selected in a select field an then automatically change the class of another element according to the selected option/value.

```
<select onchange="wow(this.value)">
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<div id="x" class="hide">x</div>

<script>
function wow(value) {
switch (value) {
    case "c":
        document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("class", "show");
        break;
    default:
        document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("class", "hide");
        break;
}
}
</script>
```

I've created/forked a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/CVxP7/112/ but I don't want to call the onchange event directly in the select tag.

Could this be done by using an EventListener or another trigger? 
I have to use plain javascript or mootools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `select` element:

```
<select id="someSelectElement"></select>
```

In your javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    document.getElementById("someSelectElement").addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        //your event handling code here
    })
})
```

**Edit**: Wrapped the `change` event listener inside the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler so as to ensure that `someSelectElement` has been loaded in the `document` before assigning the `listener` to it.

[Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfqqarh5/6/)

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve the same thing with an event listener like this

```
<select id="my-select">
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<div id="x" class="hide">x</div>

<script>
var selectElem = document.getElementById('my-select');
selectElem.addEventListener('change', function(event){
    // Then call your method
    wow(event.target.value);
});

function wow(value) {
switch (value) {
    case "c":
        document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("class", "show");
        break;
    default:
        document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("class", "hide");
        break;
}
}
</script>
```